# Nickname in quotations?

Tags: quotation-marks, nicknames

A married lady's proper name is Mrs. Rutledge Dingle.  Her first name is Frances.  When addressed by her nickname, Miss Fran, should "Miss Fran" be set off in quotation marks?
"Miss Fran" was my English teacher, and she said it should be in quotation marks since it was not her real name.

Comment: Related, but without a satisfactory answer: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/386222/quotation-marks-around-nicknames/389546#389546

Comment: @Race I thought it was quite a good answer. Obviously when writing to the lady who thinks her nickname should be in quotes, it would be courteous to put it in quotes.  Otherwise to guidance in the answer is very useful.  I'd be inclined to close this as a duplicate.

Comment: @Xanne I'm actually not criticizing anyone's answer, but it can't be marked as a duplicate without someone upvoting at least one answer on the question it's being marked a duplicate of.

Comment: Harold, your question is a good one, you might find that the answer already exists in the answers and comments of the linked question.  Cheers and welcome to EL&U!

Comment: In some contexts nicknames and the like are set apart with quotations, to make it more obvious that they are, indeed, nicknames.